# What is the difference between image denoising and image filtering

Tags: image-processing

I m start learning Image Processing,but I'm a little confused about "Image filtering" and "Image denoising". I know they both mean to reduce the noise in the image.I thought "Image filtering" is equal to "Image denoising".

But is there any difference between these two terms?

Would you please tell me the answer?

Answer (score 2):

**denoising**

- is operation specifically removing specific noise from source data set
- (usually using filtering in combination with other operations)

**filtering**

- is applying specific filter(s) on dataset
- like FIR(finite impulse response),or any kind of convolution,etc
- and this operation does not necessarily remove noise.
- For example gamma correction is also a filter technique and does not remove noise at all
- edge detectors are filters and they usually emphasize noise
- erosion/dilatation can also create new noise in data ...
- the low pass/band or smooth filters if you like reduce noise by removing specific frequency ranges from dataset but that is only byproduct exploited in denoising techniques

Comment: Many Thanks!And whether  I can say that "denoising" is including "filtering"?

Comment: @oniliste'sstar I am no expert in the field but I haven;t seen any algorithm for denoising that does not use any kind of filtering yet ...

Comment: Thanks again，I see， to apply  denoising operation we should use some kinds of filtering algorithms，but filtering algorithm are not only used for denoising.That is, denoising is filtering, but not all filtering is denoising.

Comment: @oniliste'sstar Denoising is usually done like this: 1. identify noise/artifacts in data (frequency,shape,size...) 2. construct band FIR filter to filter out unwanted information 3. the 1.2 steps are usually done on frequency domain so FFT data , filter , IFFT back to time domain. Another approach is use of dynamic tresholding to achieve specific histogram output , .... and there are surely many other approaches ...